# Find minimal sufficient statistic for truncated exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid $f(x; \theta, \lambda) = \dfrac{\lambda e^{-\lambda x}}{1-e^{-\lambda \theta}}$ for x $\in [0, \theta]$.

**I want to find**

1. A minimally sufficient statistic for $\theta$ when $\lambda$ is known and
2. A minimally sufficient statistic for $\lambda$ when $\theta$ is known.

**My Work**

I have

$$\dfrac{L(x; \theta, \lambda)}{L(y; \theta, \lambda)}  =  \dfrac{\dfrac{\lambda^n  e^{-\lambda \sum x}   }{(1-e^{-\theta \lambda})^n} 
 }{ ~~ \dfrac{\lambda^n  e^{-\lambda \sum y}   }{(1-e^{-\theta \lambda})^n} ~~}$$ for $x \in [0, \theta]$ and $y \in [0, \theta]$.

But I am unsure what to do from here because the ratio is constant whenever $\sum x_i = \sum y_i$. So does that mean that $\sum x_i$ is a minimally sufficient statistic for both?

Comment: You have to account for the indicator functions present in the likelihood.

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/404197/119261.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood for $\theta$ given $\lambda$ and a sample $\boldsymbol x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is
$$\mathcal L (\theta \mid \lambda, \boldsymbol x) \propto \lambda^n e^{-\lambda n\bar x} (1 - e^{-\lambda \theta})^{-n} \mathbb 1 (x_{(1)} \ge 0) \mathbb 1 (x_{(n)} \le \theta)$$ where $\bar x$ is the sample mean, $x_{(1)}$ is the first (minimum) order statistic, and $x_{(n)}$ is the last (maximum) order statistic.  Then choose $$h(\boldsymbol x) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda n \bar x} \mathbb 1(x_{(1)} \ge 0),$$ which is the factor that does not depend on $\theta$; choose $$g(T \mid \theta) = (1 - e^{-\lambda \theta})^{-n} \mathbb 1(T \le \theta),$$ which is the factor containing all instances of $\theta$; and choose $$T(\boldsymbol x) = x_{(n)}$$ which by the factorization theorem is sufficient for $\theta$ when $\lambda$ is known.  That it is minimal is left to the reader as an exercise.

In the case where $\theta$ is known but $\lambda$ is not, then we have the same functional form of the likelihood as above, but now our choices of $h, g, T$ may be different.  This is also left to the reader as an exercise.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for catching my error, much appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't $(1-e^ {-\lambda \theta})$ be raised to the $-n$, not $n$? Second, I am struggling to find g(T given Lambda) for the second sufficient statistic. My hunch is that $h(x) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda n\bar x} (1 - e^{-\lambda \theta})^{-n}, x \in [0, \theta])$ and $g(T \mid \lambda  =e^{-\lambda n \bar x}) \implies T(x) = \bar{X}$

Comment: @jdoe Yes, you are correct.  Clearly I was in a rush when I originally composed my answer.  As for the second sufficient statistic, you must choose $h$ such that there are only factors that do not depend on $\lambda$; i.e., $$h(\boldsymbol x) = \mathbb 1 (x_{(1)} \ge 0) \mathbb 1 (x_{(n)} \le \theta).$$  Every other factor depends on $\lambda$ so they are excluded.  Then $T$ is some function of $\boldsymbol x$ that $g$ depends on the sample only through $T$.